# UNION Query with ORDER BY SUM

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sql-order-by, union

Here is what I would like to do:

```
SELECT 
  TOP 25 tblTasks.Task, 
  tblTasks.Task_Status, 
  tblTasks.Award_Date, 
  tblTasks.End_Date, 
  Sum(tblPRs.Ceiling_Final) AS SumOfCeiling_Final, 
  tblTasks.Program, tblTasks.Prime, tblClient.Org_Top
FROM 
  (tblTasks INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblTasks.Task_ID = tblClient.Task_ID) 
   INNER JOIN tblPRs ON tblTasks.Task_ID = tblPRs.Task_ID
GROUP BY 
   tblTasks.Task, 
   tblTasks.Task_Status, 
   tblTasks.Award_Date, 
   tblTasks.End_Date, 
   tblTasks.Program, 
   tblTasks.Prime, tblClient.Org_Top
HAVING 
   (((tblTasks.Task_Status)="open"))

UNION

SELECT 
   TOP 25 tblTasks.Task, 
   tblTasks.Task_Status, 
   tblTasks.Award_Date, 
   tblTasks.End_Date, Sum(tblPRs.Ceiling_Final) AS SumOfCeiling_Final, 
   tblTasks.Program, 
   tblTasks.Prime, tblClient.Org_Top
FROM 
   (tblTasks INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblTasks.Task_ID = tblClient.Task_ID) 
    INNER JOIN tblPRs ON tblTasks.Task_ID = tblPRs.Task_ID
GROUP BY 
    tblTasks.Task, 
    tblTasks.Task_Status, 
    tblTasks.Award_Date, 
    tblTasks.End_Date, 
    tblTasks.Program, 
    tblTasks.Prime, 
    tblClient.Org_Top
HAVING 
    (((tblTasks.Task_Status)="pending"))

ORDER BY 
    Sum(tblPRs.Ceiling_Final) DESC;
```

I am entering the SQL into MS Access.  The only difference between the two queries is the HAVING parameter value.  The individual queries came from MS Access Query Design.  Each individual query when paired with the ORDER BY statement works fine and gives me the results I expect.  When I try to run them both as a UNION I get the following error:

> The ORDER BY expression (Sum(tblPRs.Ceiling_Final)) includes fields
>   that are not selected by the query.  Only those fields requested in
>   the first query can be included in  an ORDER BY expression.

Comment: are you hoping to get 25 rows **from each** of the 2 queries (50 rows in total)? or do you just want the top 25?

Comment: 25 from each for a total of 50.  I may actually change the second query to 10 for a total of 35.

Comment: Thanks to the moderator for cleaning up my post.

Answer (score 2):

nb: I have assumed you want just the 25 rows with highest `SumOfCeiling_Final`

I suggest you should to form a "derived table" first, using `union all`, then seek the `top n` rows. Please note that the `having clause` is NOT a substitute for the `where clause`. A `having clause` is necessary IF filtering conditions need aggregated values (e.g. `having sum(cost) > 1000` ). If the filtering conditions don't involve aggregates place those in the `where clause`.

```
SELECT TOP 25
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        tblTasks.Task, tblTasks.Task_Status, tblTasks.Award_Date, tblTasks.End_Date, SUM(tblPRs.Ceiling_Final) AS SumOfCeiling_Final, tblTasks.Program, tblTasks.Prime, tblClient.Org_Top
    FROM (tblTasks
    INNER JOIN tblClient
        ON tblTasks.Task_ID = tblClient.Task_ID)
    INNER JOIN tblPRs
        ON tblTasks.Task_ID = tblPRs.Task_ID
    WHERE tblTasks.Task_Status = "open"
    GROUP BY
        tblTasks.Task
       ,tblTasks.Task_Status
       ,tblTasks.Award_Date
       ,tblTasks.End_Date
       ,tblTasks.Program
       ,tblTasks.Prime
       ,tblClient.Org_Top

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        tblTasks.Task, tblTasks.Task_Status, tblTasks.Award_Date, tblTasks.End_Date, SUM(tblPRs.Ceiling_Final) AS SumOfCeiling_Final, tblTasks.Program, tblTasks.Prime, tblClient.Org_Top
    FROM (tblTasks
    INNER JOIN tblClient
        ON tblTasks.Task_ID = tblClient.Task_ID)
    INNER JOIN tblPRs
        ON tblTasks.Task_ID = tblPRs.Task_ID
    WHERE tblTasks.Task_Status = "pending"
    GROUP BY
        tblTasks.Task
       ,tblTasks.Task_Status
       ,tblTasks.Award_Date
       ,tblTasks.End_Date
       ,tblTasks.Program
       ,tblTasks.Prime
       ,tblClient.Org_Top
    ) d
ORDER BY
    SumOfCeiling_Final DESC
;
```

**NB** `UNION ALL` does NOT remove duplicates rows, `UNION` does remove duplicate rows. So, `UNION ALL` actually does LESS work i.e. it is faster. In addition, in the upper query every rows must contain Task_Status = "open" and the lower they must contain Task_Status = "pending" so the 2 queries produce rows that must be different. Although without data to verify I can't be certain, it seems you only need to use `union all`.

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried to work around the problem previously with a derived table.  Seems to me I get an error stating there is an issue with the FROM syntax.  I will try the solution at work in the AM.  Also,I need the top 25 from each query.  How would that change what you did?  The HAVING clause was created by MS Design Query - I don't know why.  I thought it should be a WHERE also.

Comment: Found a stale copy of the DB at home.  I tried your solution and it appears to work.  I also moved the SELECT TOP 25 into the two original queries (to give me 50 rows).  I have a problem with the stale DB so I cannot tell for sure if I am getting the data exactly the way I want it.  The good news is that it RUNS and I think I am on the right track now.  I am not sure why my prior attempt using the same method as yours failed - I had a syntax issue somewhere.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: So moving the TOP 25 from the outside to the each of the inside queries give me random results (query runs but the data is not what I expect).  How can we modify your solution to give TOP 25 for each of the inside queries?

Comment: The solution appears to be put each SELECT TOP query (including ORDER BY) into its own derived table then UNION ALL the derived tables.  I have this working on a minimal schema.  I'll post the final solution (if it works) once I apply to my active DB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of the following will accomplish what it looks like you are after:

```
SELECT *
FROM (put your 1st query here
      UNION
      put your 2nd query here)
ORDER BY SumOfCeiling_Final DESC;
```

-or-

```
SELECT * FROM (put your 1st query here, and include ORDER BY Sum(tblPRs.Ceiling_Final) DESC)
UNION
SELECT * FROM (put your 2nd query here, and include ORDER BY Sum(tblPRs.Ceiling_Final) DESC)
```

My sql-fu is not strong enough to know for sure that these would work, without fiddling around with actual data; speaking of which, could you set up a SQL Fiddle with the minimal schema and data to illustrate your question / problem?

EDIT: For the record, I also like the answer @Used_By_Already posted, and obviously his/her answer is very much like my first alternative; use the one that works the best for your needs.

Comment: I am a real noob at this.  No clue how to set up a Fiddle.  If you explain it I could try.  Also, as in my prior comment on prior answer, I am pretty sure I tried to get this solution to work but get an error related to FROM syntax.  Will try tomorrow.

Comment: @John  1.  go to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)  2. on the left, enter schema statements (`CREATE TABLE`, etc.) and data population statements (`INSERT`, etc) then click "Build Schema"  3. on the right, enter a query and click "Run SQL"  4. tinker away

Comment: @John  note that you can select an RDBMS; I don't think you are attempting anything that is too specific to a particular RDBMS, so any of them should do ... I believe

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting each query into a derived table, and then performing the UNION on the derived tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( placed first query here including the ORDER BY
) AS a

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM ( placed second query here including the ORDER BY
) AS b;
```